# How to get list of Call log with descending order in android?

Tags: android

How to get list of Call log with descending order in android my code is here but its not work it. it just display call log ascending order.

**My code is**

```
    @Override
    protected List<CallLogDetail> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        data = new ArrayList<CallLogDetail>();
        managedCursor1=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        int number = managedCursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int Name= managedCursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

        while (managedCursor1.moveToNext()) {
              String phNumber = managedCursor1.getString(number);
              String Names = managedCursor1.getString(Name);
             Bitmap photo = null
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(phNumber));
        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID};
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection,
                null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            contactID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

        }
        c.close();

    if (inputStream != null) {
        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    }
    String callTypeCode = managedCursor1.getString(type);

    int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
    String callType = null;
    switch (callcode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            callType = "Outgoing";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            callType = "Incoming";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            callType = "Missed";
            break;
    }
    CallLogDetail c = new CallLogDetail(Names, phNumber, photo, callType);
    data.add(c);

    Comparator<CallLogDetail> callLogDetailComparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
    Collections.sort(data, callLogDetailComparator);   }
```

i am using **Comparator** and **Collections.reverseOrder()** but its not work it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument of content provider query will sort data which you are passing null to it .

```
managedCursor1=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
```

change it to :

```
managedCursor1=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, "COLUMN_FOR_SORT DESC");
```

Answer (score 8):

"COLUMN_FOR_SORT DESC" didn't work for me.

I used:

```
Cursor managedCursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
        CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
```

which did the job.

Comment: Seriously? :O :O